# ¿Cómo aplicar 2 funciones en orden a múltiples data frames y guardar el resultado con otro nombre en R?

Tags: r, bucle-for

espero que alguien pueda ayudarme con este problema, me parece que es algo bastante básico pero en verdad no tengo mucha experiencia con esto y no logré solucionarlo por mi cuenta. A partir de una tabla original generé muestras con este código.

```
library("FactoMineR")
library("factoextra")
library(missMDA)
library(FactoInvestigate)
library(ggpubr)
library(cluster)
library(openxlsx)
library(dplyr)

datos1_2 = read.delim("TrueDim1_2ALL.txt")
datos = datos1_2[,3:21]

for (i in 1:1000){
  assign(paste0("df", i), sample_n(datos,80))
}
```

pero necesito aplicar a cada uno de los nuevos set de datos la función `imputeMCA` y posteriormente `MCA`, cada una con sus parámetros correspondientes:

```
c1 = imputeMCA(df1, ncp = 5)
mca1 = MCA(df1, tab.disj = c1$tab.disj, ncp = 5, na.method = "Average", graph = F)
```

El problema es que no se hacer el código para que ambas funciones se apliquen de manera automática en un loop en los set de datos generados. Al intentar usar `lapply` no pude agregar los parámetros de cada función y con `for` no entiendo como hacer que la función reconozca cada data frame y comience a iterar.

Aquí hay un extracto de la tabla `datos`

```
      defor1   defor2   defor3   defor4   hcronicas   cicatriz   tgranulacion   compperinasal
1   defor1_1 defor2_1 defor3_0 defor4_0 hcronicas_1 cicatriz_1 tgranulacion_1 compperinasal_1
2   defor1_1 defor2_1 defor3_1 defor4_1 hcronicas_0 cicatriz_1 tgranulacion_0 compperinasal_0
3   defor1_0 defor2_0 defor3_0 defor4_0 hcronicas_0 cicatriz_0 tgranulacion_0 compperinasal_1
4   defor1_0 defor2_0 defor3_0 defor4_0 hcronicas_0 cicatriz_0 tgranulacion_0 compperinasal_1
5   defor1_1 defor2_1 defor3_1 defor4_1 hcronicas_1 cicatriz_1 tgranulacion_0 compperinasal_0
6   defor1_0 defor2_0 defor3_0 defor4_0 hcronicas_0 cicatriz_0 tgranulacion_0 compperinasal_1
7   defor1_0 defor2_0 defor3_0 defor4_0 hcronicas_0 cicatriz_0 tgranulacion_0 compperinasal_0
8   defor1_0 defor2_0 defor3_0 defor4_0 hcronicas_0 cicatriz_0 tgranulacion_1 compperinasal_0
9   defor1_0 defor2_0 defor3_0 defor4_0 hcronicas_0 cicatriz_0 tgranulacion_0 compperinasal_1
10  defor1_1 defor2_1 defor3_1 defor4_1 hcronicas_0 cicatriz_1 tgranulacion_1 compperinasal_0
```

Answer (score 1):

Tal como lo tienes planteado, podrías hacer algo como esto:

```
for (i in 1:1000){
    df_name <- paste0("df", i)
    c1 = imputeMCA(get(df_name), ncp = 5)
    mca1 = MCA(get(df_name), tab.disj = c1$tab.disj, ncp = 5, na.method = "Average", graph = F)
}
```

Usamos [`get(<nombre de variable>)`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.5.3/topics/get) para acceder a los valores a los que apunta el nombre de variable.

De cualquier forma, te sugiero que trabajes con una única lista, para guardar cada lote de ejemplos en vez de `data.frames` separados ya que simplemente deberás manejar el índice de `1:1000` para acceder a cada elemento, te será mucho más sencillo todo:

```
df <- list()
for (i in 1:1000){
    df[[i]] <- sample_n(datos,80)
}
c1 <- list()
mca1 <- list()
for (i in 1:1000){
    c1[[i]] <- imputeMCA(df[[i]], ncp = 5)
    mca1[[i]] <- MCA(df[[i]],  tab.disj = c1[[i]]$tab.disj, ncp = 5, na.method = "Average", graph = F)
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta, no pense en el uso de `get`. Sin embargo no resulta del todo, ya que es necesario que al momento de aplicar  `imputeMCA` y `MCA`  se haya creado por cada data frame "original" uno nuevo. Por ejemplo cuando el loop tome a df1 debe crear 2 nuevos data frames: c1 y mca1, mientras que cuando tome a df2 debe crear a c2 y mca2, asi sucesivamente. Esto porque al no cambiar el nombre finalmente se genera solo un data frame mca1 (que es finalmente donde esta la información relevante) y necesito ver para cada df un mca separado. No se si me logré explicar bien.

Comment: @NicoM, con más razón te recomiendo usar listas. Las salidas `c1` y `mca1` puedes ir agregándolas cada una a una lista para luego acceder por indice a cada elemento. No pude reproducir tu ejemplo, pero verifica mi última edición

Answer (score 1):

Coincido con @Patricio Moracho que la mejor alternativa es ubicar tu output en una lista. Tener muchos elementos con nombres parecidos y estructura similar en el entorno global no es buena idea, en mi experiencia es la receta para errores silenciosos. Por ejemplo, si estás corriendo por segunda (o tercera o etc) vez tu script y falla un paso intermedio que debería actualizar todos tus `df*` en lugar de darte un error fatal que corta la ejecución del script, vas a tener resultados sobre una versión anterior de los datos. Mejor tener todo en listas (y si esas listas son anónimas aún mejor)

Si vas a trabajar con listas podrías utilizar directamente los iteradores de listas de R. En la librería `purrr::` hay varios para casos específicos que van más allá de los de R base como `lapply()` y que para este problema son muy útiles. En este caso se usan tres de esos iteradores especiales:

- `rerun()` para ejecutar el mismo código `.n` veces. En este caso sirve para hacer las muestras con `sample_n`. Lo uso con frecuencia para estimación de errores por aleatorización.
- `map2()` para iterar en dos listas (`.x` y `.y`) a la vez. En este caso sirve para iterar simultáneamente sobre los data.frame y las tablas disyuntivas con los datos imputados.
- `walk2()` para iterar una lista generando solo efecto colateral, sin output propiamente dicho. En este caso para generar todos los biplots. Uso `walk2` para iterar simultáneamente por los modelos y por una lista de nombres que uso como títulos de los gráficos.

Va un ejemplo reproducible con los datos `vnf`, que vienen en `missMDA`.

```
library(FactoMineR)
library(missMDA)
library(factoextra)
library(tidyverse) #Incluye purrr y dplyr

data(vnf)

rerun(.n = 2, sample_n(vnf, 200)) -> lista_muestras

map(lista_muestras, ~imputeMCA(.x, ncp = 5)) -> lista_imputados

map2(.x = lista_muestras, 
     .y = lista_imputados, 
     ~MCA(X = .x, 
          tab.disj = .y$tab.disj, 
          ncp = 5, 
          na.method = "Average", 
          graph = FALSE)) -> lista_modelos

map(lista_modelos, summary) #Para ver todos los sumarios

nombres <- paste("Muestra", seq(length(lista_modelos)))  #Estos nombres podrías venir de los datos

walk2(lista_modelos, nombres, ~print(fviz_mca_biplot(.x, title = .y)))  #Para generar todos los biplots con títulos

# Hacer un data.frame con los todos los eigenvalores

map(lista_modelos, "eig") %>%         #Extraer los eigenvalores de cada modelo
  map(as_tibble) %>%                  #Originalmente son matrices
  bind_rows(.id = "Muestra")   #Para un group_by después
```

Esto se podría hacer también todo en un paso, pero creo que es mejor tener las estructuras de datos intermedias `lista_muestra` y `lista_imputados`. De esta manera si hay algún problema o resultado inconsistente se pueden revisar los datos intermedios y diagnosticarlo más fácilmente. Esto es útil considerando que los errores que emite `FactoMiner` son muy poco informativos.